# Find the smallest interval you can be sure contains $g(1.8)$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $g$ be a function such that $g(2)=1$, $g′(2)=2$ and
$|g′′(x)|<0.4+(x−2)^2$
for all $x>0$.
Find the smallest interval you can be sure contains $g(1.8)$.

Your answer should be the endpoints of an open interval posed as two rational numbers separated by a comma.

Hint:

1) Find first the linear approximation $L(1.8)≈g(1.8)$.

2) Use Corollary B on page 270 to find the number $M$ such that
$|E(1.8)|<M$.

3) Your interval will then be given by $(L(1.8)−M,L(1.8)+M)$.

Have found $l(x)=2x-3$, and $g(1.8)=0.6$, but I'm now stuck on task 2). Corollary B says: 
if $|g′′(x)|< M$ for all $t$ between $a$ and $x$ (where $K$ is a constant), then $|E(x)|<(k/2)(x-a)^2$.

Comment: @Amzoti It says what it is in the question.

Comment: What is $K$? What is $k$? Something seems to be missing and/or mistyped in your transcription of Corollary B. Also, what is $E$? Much context is missing, here, and we don't have your text in front of us.